# How to measure the similarity of two documents , given the similarity of each pair of words?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, similarity

I have two documents, for example:

```
Doc1 = {'python','numpy','machine learning'}
Doc2 = {'python','pandas','tensorflow','svm','regression','R'}
```

And I also know the `similarity`(correlation) of each pair of words, e.g

```
Sim('python','python') = 1
Sim('python','pandas') = 0.8
Sim('numpy', 'R') = 0.1
```

What is the best way to measure the similarity of the two documents?

It seems that the traditional `Jaccard distance` and `cosine distance` are not a good metric in this situation.

Comment: what is datatype of your documents? string or list?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar you can just consider the document as a set of string as mentioned in the question , duplicates doesn't matter in my situation

Comment: This is way too broad. You might want to try https://cs.stackexchange.com/ for this type of question, which is not really a Python question.

Comment: @kabanus thx for reminding, I will repost my question to stackexchange

Comment: @Ken.W No problem. Do not forget to delete it here once copied as to not create a cross site duplicate.

Comment: Do you have word vectors for the individual words?

Comment: @grshankar No, I have tired to use word vectors to calculate the similarity of two words but the effect was not ideal as expected. So I used another approach to define the similarity of two words

Comment: what approach did you use for word similarity ?

Comment: @grshankar e.g Sim('python','pandas') = co-appearance('python','pandas')  in corpus / appearance('pandas') in corpus

Answer (score 0):

I like [a book by Peter Christen](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642311635)  on this issue.

Here he describes a **Monge-Elkan** similarity measure between two sets of strings.
For each word from the first set you find the closest word from the second set and divide it by the number of elements in the first set.
You can see its description [on page 30 here](https://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachgebiete/naumann/folien/SS13/DPDC/DPDC_12_Similarity.pdf).